# Problem with limit of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am supposed to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{\left ( x,y \right )\rightarrow \left ( 0,1 \right )}\frac{x-y+1}{x+y-1}$$

I do not understand the step, where the substitution: y=kx+1 was used, in the way that:

$$\lim_{\left ( x \right )\rightarrow \left ( 0 \right )}\frac{x-kx}{x+kx}$$

Can anyone please explain it to me? why we choose suxh a function?

Comment: Well, it's obviously possible to approach the point $(0,1)$ in infinitely many ways. In this case, we are checking what happens if we approach it by a line defined with $y=kx+1$ for some $k$. If the limit exists, the value should not depend on the value of $k$. Can you see what happens in that case? What is the conclusion for the value of the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to show that by arriving at $(0,1)$ along different paths, you will find different limits, so that the 2D limit does not exist.

In this case, they use the paths $y-1=kx$, which are straight lines of varying slope, and for $(x,y)\ne(0,1)$,

$$\frac{x-y+1}{x+y-1}=\frac{x-kx}{x+kx}=\frac{1-k}{1+k}.$$

---

We can solve this in another way, by following the lines $x=0$ and $y=1$.

- $x=0\to\dfrac{x-y+1}{x+y-1}=\dfrac{-y+1}{y-1}\to-1$;
- $y=1\to\dfrac{x}{x}\to1$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

$y=kx+1$ represents  the straight line passing through the point $(0,1)$ with slope $k$. In order that the limit of the function as $(x,y) \to (0,1)$ exists it is necessary that the limits through all these lines are the same. In this case the limit varies with the  slope $k$ so the function  does not have a limit.

Comment: Now, I undesrand, okay thanks